# Replace an image when clicked

Tags: c#, wpf

Not sure if the title makes any sense.

In my WPF application I would like the window to contain a small image, icon size. When the user clicks on the image another one simply replaces it, that holds the same dimensions.

I have all the images loaded into my project for C#/WPF. (By the way there are 3 images)

**What I have been trying:**

- I tried changing the opacity in the code-behind to make one image
  have full opacity and the others have no opacity. Didn't work as the 
  first toggle would strangely make all images disappear.
- I also tried dynamically changing the image source in the code-behind. I
  used if statements and a field to determine what image to switch
  the source to. Code being:

  ```
      if (toggle == 1)
      {
          thebutton.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/images/icon2.png", UriKind.Relative));
          toggle = 2;
      }
  ```

Also did not work (made it blank, rather than switching to another image) but I feel like there is an obvious way I'm not seeing.

What I initially wanted to do was simply (like in graphics programs) raise and lower the images to the top and bottom to determine which ones the user should see. All that matters is the visual. The user clicks image 1, image 1 disappears and image 2 appears in its place, and so on for image 3.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Build Action of the image files to `Resource`, and load them by [Resource File Pack URIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
thebutton.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/icon2.png"));
```